# Помогите разобраться со знаками препинания в предложении

Tags: пунктуация

Но, в общем, он был почти тот же, что в Москве: приветлив, но сдержан, говорил довольно оживленно, но еще более просто и кратко, и во время разговора все думал о чем-то своем, предоставляя собеседнику самому улавливать переходы в скрытом течении своих мыслей, и все глядел на море сквозь стекла пенсне, слегка приподняв лицо...

Comment: Елизавета, я убрал метку "синтаксис" и поставил "пунктуация". Если я ошибся и Вас действительно интересует синтаксический разбор предложения, пожалуйста, напишите об этом в тексте вопроса.

Comment: Текст принадлежит перу Бунина (http://chehov.niv.ru/chehov/vospominaniya/bunin.htm)?

Comment: Интересно, что даже в Нацкорпусе есть две версии, одна с запятой после "кратко", другая без нее:  http://search1.ruscorpora.ru/search.xml?env=alpha&mycorp=&mysent=&mysize=&mysentsize=&mydocsize=&dpp=&spp=&spd=&text=lexform&mode=main&sort=gr_tagging&lang=ru&nodia=1&req=%ED%EE+%E5%F9%E5+%E1%EE%EB%E5%E5+%EF%F0%EE%F1%F2%EE+%E8+%EA%F0%E0%F2%EA%EE+%E8+%E2%EE+%E2%F0%E5%EC%FF

Answer (score 1):

```
 Интересно, что даже в Нацкорпусе есть две
 версии, одна с запятой после "кратко", другая без нее
```

Это не две версии, это два произведения. Дело в том, что Бунин написал несколько очерков о Чехове. Сначала по просьбе Горького он участвует в создании сборника памяти Чехова, очерк так и называется - "Памяти Чехова", он вышел в 1905 году в 3-м сборнике товарищества "Знание". Потом были дополнения к воспоминаниям о Чехове - заметки Бунина "Из записной книжки", опубликованные в "Русском слове" в 1914 году. Готовя своё Полное собрание сочинений в приложении к журналу "Нива" (1915 г.),Бунин объединил оба очерка и назвал "О Чехове. Из записной книжки". Для зарубежных изданий он переработал и объединил оба мемуарных очерка, озаглавив просто "Чехов". В 1953 году в Париже он работал над письмами Чехова по советскому изданию писем. Книга осталась незаконченной, была издана женой Бунина посмертно. Я посмотрела очерк "О Чехове", он есть у меня в печатном виде в Собрании сочинений 1988 г. под редакцией Ю Бондарева.Там в таком виде:

*(I) Но в общем он был почти тот же,(3) что в Москве:(4) (II) приветлив,(5) но сдержан,(6) говорил довольно оживленно,(7) но еще более просто и кратко,(8) и во время разговора все думал о чем-то своем,(9) предоставляя собеседнику самому улавливать переходы в скрытом течении своих мыслей,(10) и все глядел на море сквозь стекла пенсне,(11) слегка приподняв лицо...*

Используя нумерацию Риммы Михайловой, за исключением обособления "в общем" (это действительно не вводное слово), позволю себе не согласиться с тем, что двоеточие разделяет простые предложения в БСП, по-моему, это однородные члены с обобщающим словом тот же:

.*..он был тот же, что в Москве: приветлив, но сдержан*

Тогда и запятые перед И будут объяснены повторяющимся союзом при однородных сказуемых:

*... он был тот же: приветлив, но сдержан, говорил  оживленно, но кратко, и  все думал о чем-то своем, и все глядел на море ...*

У нас есть правило: если однородных членов более двух (а их у нас 4) и союзы повторяются не перед каждым из них,  то запятая ставится  между всеми однородными членами, в том числе и перед первым союзом. Хотя пунктограмма 10, конечно, объясняется и обособлением деепричастного оборота. Одно другому не мешает.

Answer (score 0):

**(I)** Но,(1) в общем,(2) он был почти тот же,(3) что в Москве:(4) **(II)** приветлив,(5) но сдержан,(6) говорил довольно оживленно,(7) но еще более просто и кратко,(8) и во время разговора все думал о чем-то своем,(9) предоставляя собеседнику самому улавливать переходы в скрытом течении своих мыслей,(10) и все глядел на море сквозь стекла пенсне,(11) слегка приподняв лицо...

Я бы объяснила пунктуацию таким образом.

(4) Двоеточие — **(I): (II).** — бессоюзное сложное предложение, вторая часть которого разъясняет, поясняет, раскрывает смысл его первой части (каким именно он был).
[*Он был: приветлив, но сдержан, говорил, и думал, и глядел*.]

(1) и (2) —  *в общем* —  вводное слово, выделяем запятыми.
(3) —  запятая перед подчинительным союзом ***что***.
(5) и (7) —  запятая перед сочинительным (противительным) союзом ***но***.
(6), (8), (10) — запятые между однородными сказуемыми, соединёнными в том числе двумя сочинительными союзами ***и***.
(9), (10), (11) —  обособление деепричастных оборотов.

**Дополнение**
Отсутствие в некоторых источниках запятой после слова "кратко", думаю, связано с другим пониманием и, соответственно, с другим "разделением на группы" однородных членов.
[*Он был: приветлив, но сдержан, говорил и думал, и глядел.*]

Некоторые источники ([Русская литература в школе](https://books.google.ee/books?id=URNJDwAAQBAJ&pg=PA653&lpg=PA653&dq=%D0%9D%D0%BE,%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5,%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5:%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD,%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE,%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE,%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC,%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&source=bl&ots=V3m_x9WlDN&sig=SLEKTGp3Hx6vOQcoE1M9lvblnH0&hl=ru&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwiYwZDU1J_dAhVFK1AKHWETDA4Q6AEwAnoECAkQAQ#v=onepage&q=%D0%9D%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B2%20%D0%BE%D0%B1%D1%89%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BE%D0%BD%20%D0%B1%D1%8B%D0%BB%20%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%87%D1%82%D0%B8%20%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%82%20%D0%B6%D0%B5%2C%20%D1%87%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%20%D0%9C%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B2%D0%B5%3A%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BB%D0%B8%D0%B2%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B6%D0%B0%D0%BD%2C%20%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BB%20%D0%B4%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%BD%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%BD%D0%BE%20%D0%B5%D1%89%D0%B5%20%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B5%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D0%B8%20%D0%BA%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%82%D0%BA%D0%BE%2C%20%D0%B8%20%D0%B2%D0%BE%20%D0%B2%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D1%8F%20%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%B3%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B0%20%D0%B2%D1%81%D0%B5%20%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BC%D0%B0%D0%BB%20%D0%BE%20%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%82%D0%BE%20%D1%81%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B5%D0%BC%2C%20%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BB%D1%8F%D1%8F%20%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%B1%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%B5%D0%B4%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA&f=false)) считают **в общем** наречием, имеющим значение *в общих чертах, в целом, не вдаваясь в детали,* и запятыми его не выделяют.
[**В ОБЩЕМ**](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/92/%D0%B2)

Comment: Если Вы хотите объяснить запятую (8) повторяющимся союзом *и*, то я не согласен, потому что нет там повторяющегося союза *и*. Говорил и **во время разговора** все думал и все глядел. А запятая (10) не есть запятая между однородными сказуемыми.

Comment: Запятую (8) я интуитивно оправдываю, но какое правило под это подвести?

Comment: Вы, наверно, пропустили в моем ответе: _(9), (10), (11) — обособление деепричастных оборотов._  Запятая (10) нужна в любом случае. А про спорную запятую (8) и _в общем_ - разногласия имеются и в Нацкорпусе (и не только там). Я разделила однородные сказуемые так, как **я** их ощущаю - с запятой после "кратко"..

Comment: "Запятая (10) нужна в любом случае" ==> Запятая (10) стоит **только   потому**, что обособляет оборот.

Comment: Под любым случаем я, собственно, и подразумевала запятую, закрывающую дееприч. оборот (вне зависимости от всех остальных рассуждений и знаков). Не понимаем друг друга. Жаль.

Answer (score 0):

Вторая часть предложения (после двоеточия): ...**(он был) приветлив, но сдержан, говорил (1) и  всё думал, (2) и (он) все глядел...**

Запятая 1: между однородными сказуемыми, тесно связанными по смыслу.

Запятая 2: присоединительный характер союза И, можно рассматривать конструкцию как отдельное предложение.

Comment: "Запятая 1: между однородными сказуемыми" => Какими именно?

Comment: Говорил и думал (при этом), они же тесно связаны по смыслу.

Comment: Если два однородных сказуемых (говорил и думал) соединены союзом *и*, то по какому правилу появляется запятая перед *и*?

Comment: Там группы однородных членов: (1) (он был) приветлив, но сдержан, (2) говорил  и всё думал.