# Запятая перед союзом "и", если есть два ряда однородных членов

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, однородные-члены

Этот вопрос родился в результате раздумий над другим вопросом ([Помогите разобраться со знаками препинания в предложении](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/443875/%d0%9f%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c%d1%81%d1%8f-%d1%81%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%bf%d0%b8%d0%bd%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b2-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8)).
Постараюсь сформулировать его в обобщенно. Допустим есть два однородных члена предложения, соединенные союзом *и*. В таком случае запятая перед *и* не нужна. Но вот между ними вклинился другой ряд однородных членов, связанных союзом *но*. В таком случае перед упомянутым *и* делается пауза, интуитивно хочется поставить запятую. Требуется ли она по правилам?

Пример (придумано мной):

> Она умела петь громко, но очень тепло и проникновенно(,) и танцевать весело, но элегантно.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Она умела петь громко, но очень тепло и проникновенно, и (она умела) танцевать весело, но элегантно.**

Я бы поставила здесь запятую, разделив высказывание на два предложения в составе ССП. Это как раз объясняется расчлененностью и распространенностью двух частей.

Такое решение связано с наличием паузы после первой части, так как **невозможно две части соединить в одну фразу** из-за наличия запятой (паузы) между однородными обстоятельствами (перед союзом НО).

Я не думаю, чтобы этот частный вариант рассматривался в правилах. Эту задачу надо решать самостоятельно или посмотреть решение в похожих  текстах.

Comment: Мне такой ход мысли кажется искусственным. Хотим поставить запятую — объявляем, то это ССП.  "Она умела петь громко и танцевать весело." Каким образом несколько дополнительных слов  превратили это предложение в ССП?

Comment: Вы всегда работаете в рамках одного грамматического принципа,  а я вижу, что слитной интонационной фразы из четырех "кусочков" не склеишь, поэтому пауза обязательна и запятая тоже. Так что запятую поставьте,  а объяснение этому ищите такое, какое вам нравится. Да и что искать-то. В теме однородных сказуемых допускается двойная трактовка: однородные члены или ССП. Она умела петь громко и танцевать весело. Разумеется,  это однородные члены. А если вы к каждому однородному члену добавите сложную конструкцию из других однородных членов, то это будет ССП.